# Locating and pinging a satellite

Tags: networking, ping, icmp, satellite

I want to ping a satellite, or ping some far off computer and know for sure that somewhere in the traceroute is a satellite hop

I know that if I ping a computer in , say, australia (i am in the UK) there is a high chance it will have gone through a satellite at some point, but the only method I have seen online for identifying a satellite hop is that there will be a high response time (600~ms), this doesnt sound like an guarentee'd method for identifying a satellite though.

Towards the end of the traceroute there is a hop that just have asterisks and apparently this could mean that the hop is filtering out icmp, is this common for satellites? if so then could the asterisk'd hops be satellites?

How can I be sure that a hop is a satellite, or is there a list that might contain satellites and their ip addresses?

Comment: Why do think it will go via satellite? There are plenty of undersea cables ...

Comment: i was actually pinging what i think is an ISP on the pacic island of Tonga (tcc.to), im just assuming the end hop resides on the island

Comment: Tonga is cabled http://www.submarinecablemap.com/#/submarine-cable/tonga-cable

Comment: ahh excellent link. so if you wanted to ping a satellite or go vai a satellite, what would you do?

Comment: No idea....... :/

Comment: Most satellites are managed out of band - that is, they have a separate uplink dedicated to managing the satellite, usually using a different dedicated antennas and communications protocols.  You, as a customer of a satellite provider, just have your data passed through the satellite back to the ground - you can't interact with it in any way. From https://www.quora.com/Do-communication-satellites-have-ip-addresses-If-so-what-are-they

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Routing_in_Space

Comment: so traceroutes dont show satellite hops?

Comment: I already told you. No idea.

Answer (score 1):

Satellite links are often tunnelled, encapsulation will prevent you from seeing it. They're also low priority so the chances of traversing them unless you REALLY need to are very low. For pretty much everywhere a satellite can go, fibre exists running at 1000x+ greater bandwidth.

http://www.bentley-walker.com/articles/101

Another issue with sats is common TCP spoofing.